# Solving without Logarithm?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> For example, $$2^{x+1}=3^x$$

Usually we solve this by using logarithm, so we would get $x=-\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 2-\ln 3}$. So I was asked to solve this without logarithm, is it even possible?

Comment: I don't think its possible here, unless you want silly answers like $x=-\infty$ or a numeric answer.

Comment: Or if we are working in a finite cyclic group (also silly since no context hints at this).

Comment: It quite depends on what you mean by "solve this" and what you mean by "using algorithm". Simple algebra gives
$
2=\big(\frac32\big)^x.
$
Then by *definition*, one has
$
x=\log_{3/2}2.
$

Comment: Use numerical method , graphing

Comment: To add to @Jack 's answer, if by "solve" you mean "end up with $x$ on only side of the equation", then Jack's answer does that. Similarly you could take the reciprocal of both sides to get $\frac12=(\frac23)^x$. Various other manipulations would also give $x$ on only 1 side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to get an exact answer without logarithms. A logarithm is, **by definition**, the solution to such an equation. What is $\log_2(3)$? Well, **by definition**, it's the solution to $2^x=3$.

Trying to solve your equation without using logarithms is like trying to find the area of a circle without using $\pi$.

There are many different numerical methods you could use.

It's probably best to re-write the equation as follows:

$$2^{x+1}=3^x \iff 2\cdot 2^x=3^x \iff 
\frac{2^x}{3^x} = \frac{1}{2} \iff \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\! x} = \frac{1}{2}$$

From here, you could use trial and error, interval bisection, or linear interpolation.

Newton-Raphson could be used, but the derivative of $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x$ involves a logarithm, so you probably aren't interested in that.

Answer (score -2):

we can solve this question with the help of graphs, where they intersect will be the solutions

https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/b4re4msk